# Container height issue when laid on stack and positioned

Tags: flutter, dart

In the below code when i need the bottom border of the container with some colors and at the same time i need the border radius so its not possible at the same container so that i planned to do it like in the below code , issue is my second container inside the positioned also stays in the height of 10 same time second container (height won't be specified for second container its dynamic content) which means height of the first container for the border, anyone help me out.

This is how I'm getting:

[image]

This is how I want:

[image]

```
class NotificationItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final int seen;
  final String message;
  final String displayTime;
  final int notificationId;
  final NotificationType type;

  const NotificationItemWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.imageUrl,
      required this.message,
      required this.type,
      required this.displayTime,
      required this.notificationId,
      required this.seen});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NotificationListViewModel viewModel =
        Provider.of<NotificationListViewModel>(context);
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          onTap: () {
            viewModel.navigateToRespectiveNotificationScreen(
                notificationId, type);
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 10,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: colorForItem(type),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 1,
                left: -1,
                right: -1,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      boxShadow: const [
                        BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, -1),
                          blurRadius: 4,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 32,
                        height: 32,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: colorForItem(type), shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                          child: Image.network(
                            imageUrl,
                            width: 20,
                            height: 20,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 12),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(message,
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .headlineMedium
                                  ?.copyWith(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: seen == 0
                                      ? ColorsManager.blackColor
                                      : ColorsManager.textGray)))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6, top: 6),
          child: Text(displayTime,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium?.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 10,
                  color: ColorsManager.textGray)),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20)
      ],
    );
  }

  Color colorForItem(NotificationType type) {
    switch (type) {
      case NotificationType.appointmentStatusApproved:
        return ColorsManager.parrotGreen;

      case NotificationType.appointmentStatusDeclined:
        return ColorsManager.russianRed;

      default:
        return ColorsManager.primaryVariant;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `Stack()` and `Positioned()` widgets to achieve the design you are looking for. You can do it in a simpler way by adding another boxShadow on bottom side and unblurred.

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    boxShadow: const [
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(0, -1),
        blurRadius: 4,
         color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
      ),
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(0, 2),
        blurRadius: 0,
        color: colorForItem(type),
      ),],),
),
```

Notice the property of `boxShadow` takes a `list`. So you can add as many `BoxShadow` as you want, and increase the height/width by making the offset (x,y) number higher

Comment: Thank you for the response! it works good. (I must be noticed the  property of boxShadow).

Comment: Im glad to hear. Please mark the answer as correct :) thanks and happy coding